# Sub-query in Knex

Tags: knex.js

I'm looking to essentially make this sort of query in Knex, but I can't quite get it to work:

```sql
select distinct *
from
(
  select *, 1 as rank from table1 where Word like 'mike'
  union
  select *, 2 as rank from table1 where Word like 'mike%'
  union
  select *, 3 as rank from table1 where Word like '%mike%'
) as X
order by WordOrder
```

I noticed a similar issue [here](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/27) and tried to follow their advice, but can't seem to spot my bug (or if this is even the proper way of doing this in the first place).

```js
var q = DB.knex('Users').select("*", "1 as rank").where("User", "like", query).
    union(function() {
        this.select("*", "2 as rank").where("User", "like", query + "%")
    }).
    union(function() {
        this.select("*", "3 as rank").where("User", "like", query + "%")
    });

DB.knex("Users").distinct("*").from('(' + q.toString() + ') as X').
    orderBy('rank').select().then(...)
```

If it's any help, that particular query generates the following error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1`` order by `rank` asc' at line 1, sql: select distinct * from `select` as ``1`` order by `rank` asc, bindings:
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Version 0.6 of knex allows you to use subqueries pretty much anywhere now. Pop this in the chrome console at http://knexjs.org and you should see it gives you what you're looking for

```
knex.distinct('*').from(function() {
  this.union(function() {
    this.select('*', '1 as rank').from('table1').where('Word', 'like', 'mike')
  }).union(function() {
    this.select('*', '2 as rank').from('table1').where('Word', 'like', 'mike%')
  }).union(function() {
    this.select('*', '3 as rank').from('table1').where('Word', 'like', '%mike%')
  })
  .as('X')
}).orderBy('WordOrder').toString()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is more or less what I was originally looking for.

Comment: I think, this should be the accepted answer. Thanks @tgriesser!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: This answer refers to older version of knex. See [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24400624/363448).**

When I do this, I use the `knex.raw` functionality. You can put any raw SQL in there. Like this:

```
 var selectRaw = "SUM( IF( "+ table.id +" = 1, "+ table.value +", 0.00 )) as customAlias";
 query.column( knex.raw( selectRaw ) );
```

You might even be able to build the query with knex, and then just use the `.toString()` method to fill `knex.raw`. My example was not part of their API (those `IF`s...).

Comment: I ended up doing something like that. I created a query for each of those unioned selects, to-string'd them, and then built another query out of them. The reason I wanted to use the query builder was because it does a nice job of sanitizing input. Don't want any injection attacks.

Comment: Also, just FYI you can now bind parameters in raw statements in 0.6+, even when they're interpolated into other queries, it maintains the correct bindings

Comment: I would highly recommend making @tgriesser's answer the accepted one, as this is what reflects reality nowadays.