# Select from an existing query in knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I'm building a query using `knex.js`, given an existing sub query. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24400624/1597872) answer, and [this](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/538) thread in GitHub, I tried the following:

```
const knex = require("knex")({client: 'pg'});

const subQuery = knex.queryBuilder().select(1);

const query = knex.queryBuilder().select('*').from(subQuery);

console.log(query.toString());
```

But the result was:

```
select * from select 1
```

Which obviously has a syntax error. My expected result is:

```
select * from (select 1)
```

Why doesn't it add the parentheses, and how can I change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your way, how you did it seems correct and I would say that it is bug in `knex` why it doesn't work (I'm collaborator in `knex`).

Anyways there are couple of ways to do it...

```
const knex = require("knex")({client: 'pg'});

const subQuery = knex.select(1).as('t1');
const query = knex.select('*').from(subQuery);
console.log(query.toSQL());

{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [],
  __knexQueryUid: '69d240ad-f5f8-4bc4-8c1d-fb9432af1da2',
  sql: 'select * from (select 1) as "t1"' }
```

Or you can use older style with `function()` subquery, which doesn't require `.as()`, but supports it...

```
const query = knex.select('*').from(sq => sq.select(1));
console.log(query.toSQL());

{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [],
  __knexQueryUid: '31beb080-c89a-43b2-b112-546077330e82',
  sql: 'select * from (select 1)' }
```

Comment: I've used the 1st solution, and the `as('t1')` worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Greatly simplified my code. Thank you very much. You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

An ugly (but working) solution I found was using `knex.raw` and `subQuery.toString`:

```
const query = knex.queryBuilder()
    .select('*')
    .from(knex.raw(`(${subQuery})`);
```

I don't believe this is the best answer, and I'm sure I'm missing something, so I don't accept this answer yet.

Comment: You should never use `.toString()` for passing raw queries around... this will cause knex to interpolate e.g. parameter bindings by itself and it won't be able to use database driver's implementation to prevent SQL injection. `.toSQL()` gives you bindings and sql separately.